# How to setup an ArangoDB on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, arangodb

I want to host a Telegram python bot which uses ArangoDB as its database. Can you help with creating ArangoDB on Heroku? GitHub repo for bot: https://github.com/mojurasu/kantek
Edit: I am not sure if Heroku postgres will work with Arango

Comment: Postgres will definitely not work with ArangoDB - these are 2 independent database providers

Answer (score 2):

Heroku is a service that offers hosting your stateless application in containers persisting your data with Postgres + Redis.

ArangoDB in contrast is a multi model Database - it keeps state for you, for which it needs storage volumes which Heroku doesn't offer.

As Heroku offers you managing databases of your application stack for you, it doesn't do so for ArangoDB.

If its about having a managed ArangoDB so you don't need to care about it, there is [ArangoGraph Insights Platform](https://cloud.arangodb.com/home) where you can get ArangoDB as a service, however, you need to manage your application containers on your own.